# how to call a function from step inspector in vr builder unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am using VR builder in Unity, and in any given step, as a behaviour, i want to call a function inside a script attached to a gameobject.

i couldnt find a way to do it. the only makeshift workaround i found is to use enable component option in step inspector, which calls OnEnable function. Also i am not talking about making behaviour scripts, i just want to call a function with or without parameters thats all.

so is there any way to call a function from a behaviour in step inspector?